# How to fail laravel route for unit testing?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I have following code in my controller

```
public function store(CreateSpecialityRequest $request) 
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $speciality = $this->specialityRepository->create($request->all());
        DB::commit();

        return redirect()->route('specialities.index')
            ->with('success', 'Speciality Added successfully');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return $e->getMessage();
        return redirect()->route('specialities.index')
            ->with('error', 'Specialities details updating failed');
    }

}
```

My Testcase

```
$speciality = [
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'description' => $faker->sentence,
            'icon' => $uploadedFile
        ];

        $this->post('/specialities', $speciality)
            ->assertResponseStatus(302)
            ->assertRedirectedToRoute('specialities.index')
            ->assertSessionHas(['success' => 'Speciality Added successfully'])
            ->followRedirects()
            ->assertViewHas('specialities');
```

On my code coverage it shows that I have covered only try block
I want to cover catch block too. How can I fail my route in unit tests? to get into catch block

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass an empty array for input and the create method should throw `QueryException`.

```
$this->post('/specialities', []);
```

You should also look at your catch block return. You're immediately returning the exception message, the redirect with message never gets called.

```
return $e->getMessage();
return redirect()->route('specialities.index')
            ->with('error', 'Specialities details updating failed');
```

Comment: For empty array I have formRequest validation for that I have already written test. I have used Mockery throw exception in create method to fail my test case . Thanks for reply .